# How to restrict the control from zooming in beyond its parent

Tags: wpf

I have wpf application. in which i have different types of controls which are placed in different rows and columns of grid. and i have enabled zooming for each control. I can zoom a control but goes beyond the gridrow/column it belongs to.
I have followed the below way to do zoom`Point p = e.MouseDevice.GetPosition(image);

```
        Matrix m = image.RenderTransform.Value;
        if (e.Delta > 0)
            m.ScaleAtPrepend(1.1, 1.1, p.X, p.Y);
        else
            m.ScaleAtPrepend(1/1.1, 1/1.1, p.X, p.Y);

        image.RenderTransform = new MatrixTransform(m);`
```

I want to enable the zooming with in the row/column that the control has been placed. Any ideas on this?

Comment: How do you zoom your controls? By layout transform?

Comment: I have used matrix transform, i have edited the question with the code